# Python, SUM list of dictionaries by matching key value

Tags: python, list

I have found similar solutions to what I am looking to do, and it works to an extent. However not exactly as I need. Your assistance is appreciated.

**Problem**: I want to make a new list/dictionary per OrderID and its TradeVolume. You can have multiple Trades but only one OrderID. If an OrderID has more than one trade associated to it, I want to sum the TradeVolume.

I have a list of unique orderIDs that I made from a JSON response:

```
order_ids = [39663397, 39982478]
```

Trimmed for example purposes.
Here is the JSON that I will be running through

```
   trades = [{'TradeNumber': 39784054, 'OrderNumber': 39982478, 'TradeVolume': 1.0}, {'TradeNumber': 39784055, 'OrderNumber': 39982478, 'TradeVolume': 1.0}]
```

Expected Result:

```
{'OrderNumber': 39982478, 'TotalTradeVolume': 2.0}
```

Current output:

```
{'OrderNumber': 39982478, 'TotalTradeVolume': 1.0}, 
{'OrderNumber': 39982478, 'TotalTradeVolume': 2.0}
```

As you can see, on the first pass its adds it as expected. But with the second pass, I expect it to update the value already in the list, and not add a new one. The sum is correct in the second item.

Here is my code snippet that does the work:

```
for orderid in order_ids:
sum = 0
for trade in trades:
    if orderid == trade['OrderNumber']:
        sum = sum + trade['TradeVolume']

        if orderid not in total_per_order:
            print('not in,  adding...')
            total_per_order.append({'OrderNumber': orderid, 'TotalTradeVolume': sum})
        else:
            print('already here, updating...')
            total_per_order.update({'TotalTradeVolume': sum})
```

From running this in debug mode, it never seems to find that the OrderNumber is already in the new list I created. Pretty certain this is where my mistake is.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess the expected order number should be 39663397, for the given example right?

Comment: Yes, all just examples. Let me update to make it clear.

Comment: `trades` is defined as a list, so each dictionary is a separate unrelated item in that list.  If you want `trades` to not have repeats then it should be a dictionary where OrderNumber is the distinct key and it has a list of the multiple trades (or just the total)

Comment: `total_per_order` is your list of dictionaries, so of course the string `orderid` will never be in that list. Rather, you want to check if any of your dictionaries have a specific key-value pair: `if any(current_dict["OrderNumber"] == orderid for current_dict in total_per_order):`

Comment: Yes, that's It. I just didn't know the correct way to then go and look for the key-value pair. I will give this a go. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve for your expected result, you also can bring the if statement at the bottom of your code to a higher level:

```
total_per_order = []
for orderid in order_ids:
    sum = 0
    for trade in trades:
        if orderid == trade['OrderNumber']:
            sum = sum + trade['TradeVolume']

if orderid not in total_per_order:
    print('not in,  adding...')
    total_per_order.append({'OrderNumber': orderid, 'TotalTradeVolume': sum})
else:
    print('already here, updating...')
    total_per_order.update({'TotalTradeVolume': sum})
```

Result:

```
not in,  adding...
[{'OrderNumber': 39982478, 'TotalTradeVolume': 2.0}]
```

Comment: Noting here that the else will never run, as Paul M pointed out, no key-value pair in the list, as the way I'm looking for it is wrong. But your solution still works in the sense that we moved the if.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
total_per_order = []
for orderid in order_ids:
    total_per_order.append({
        'OrderNumber': orderid,
        'TotalTradeVolume': sum(t['TradeVolume'] for t in trades if t['OrderNumber'] == orderid)}
```

Result; `total_per_order =`:

```
[{'OrderNumber': 39663397, 'TotalTradeVolume': 0},
 {'OrderNumber': 39982478, 'TotalTradeVolume': 2.0}]
```